# Replacing colored Text in QTextEdit

Tags: python, colors, pyqt5, qtextedit, qmdiarea

I hope doing good I am facing an issue with changing the color of only searched string from a file in QTextEdit and I have used replace method with "colored" module but I am not getting colored string, in console window I am getting colored string of selected one but in "QTextEdit" I am getting this
[image: I seached word "proc"]
before searching I am getting this
[image: Befor Searching]

Here I need to change the color of only searched word.

Here is my code
`

```
with open(self.new_path, 'r') as f2:
            for line in f2:
                if re.findall(tex, line):
                    color = colored(tex, 'blue', attrs=())
                    line = line.replace(tex, color)
                self.w.append(line)
        self.sub.setWidget(self.w)
        self.sub.setWindowTitle('Sabrefiles'+" "+str(treewid.count))
        self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(self.sub)
        self.sub.show()
```

`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: from the path I read a file and I found a string from lines "tex" I need to change the color of the string "tex" and replace that into file.

Comment: 1. strings don't have colors; 2. you asked about changing the result in the textedit, but then you wrote that you want to *replace* it in the file. Take your time and try to clarify what you want, as right now your question and code are just confusing.

Comment: The [colored package](https://pypi.org/project/colored/) uses [ANSI Escape Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to format text in a console. The QTextEdit class knows nothing about such codes, so what you're trying do simply won't work. You need to use HTML instead. Try something like this: `color = f'<span style="color: blue">{tex}</span>'`. Alternatively, consider using the [QSyntaxHighlighter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsyntaxhighlighter.html) class.

Comment: It works perfectly how can apply this to list of strings in file and to integers also ??